# Redirect HTTP to HTTPS for ALL Subdomains

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I'm trying to write a rule that means if anyone goes to any address across the whole domain, it will replace http: with https:

My current rule is;

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://mydomain.co.uk/members$1 [R,L]
```

This works for my main domain but I have different subdomains which I need to write to work in the same way. I'd ideally not like to write a rule for each of the subdomains.

If I go to **https**://example.mydomain.co.uk/members it shows the correct content but if I got **http**://example.mydomain.co.uk/members it redirects to https://mydomain.co.uk

Thanks in advance for your help!

EDIT: I forgot to mention, this rule is in my /members directory not root.

Comment: Do either of the answers work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this:

```
ServerAlias *.mydomain.com

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+)\.mydomain\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1.mydomain.com/$1 [R=302,L]
```

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```